# mouseDown event not called when NSControls are clicked, not even on subclassed NSView

Tags: cocoa, nsevent

How to get the current NSControl clicked on NSWindow? I have a mouse down event on NSWindowController, 
 `-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {`  
but when I click inside NSControls placed on NSWindow I dont get the mouse down event called at all.
  
 I have even subclassed NSControls to custom NSViews but I dont receive their mouse down events too when clicked inside. I added  `setAcceptsTouchEvents`to yes and calling acceptsFirstResponder but its not helping. Surprisingly, when I click on NSWindow and not on any NSControls I get the mousedown event. 
 What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
 - (void) mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
if ( ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask) != 0)
{
    [self setFloatValue:100.0f];
    [self.target performSelector:self.action withObject:self];
}
else
    [super mouseDown:theEvent];
}
```

edit:

The target should be the class instance where that method is implemented. So, for example, if you had an IBAction in your app delegate that was connected to your slider called sliderReport: then do this:

```
   [self sendAction:@selector(sliderReport:) to:[NSApp delegate]];
```

Comment: nope, its not called perhaps the control is not going inside the function when i click any NSControl. I have a IKImageView and 2 IKImageBrowserViews. Basically I have added a separate NSWindowcontroller and then added NSControls on its xib. controls are already connected to fileowner

Comment: well, i want to detect a single click on IKImageBrowserView control. I am sub-classsing the view and have added methods becomeFirstResponder , acceptsFirstResponder and acceptsFirstMouse for overriding. But the problem is the method -(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent { on NSWindowController is not called when I click inside any NS IBoutlets.